# why does sort with uniq not work together

Tags: perl

I have the following script:

```
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;
use Data::Dumper;

my @x = (3,2);
my @y = (4,3);

print "unique results \n";
print Dumper([uniq(@x,@y)]);

print "sorted unique results\n";
print Dumper([sort uniq(@x,@y)]);
```

The output is

```
unique results 
$VAR1 = [
          3,
          2,
          4
        ];
sorted unique results
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          3,
          3,
          4
        ];
```

So it looks that sort does not work with uniq.
I did not understand why.

I ran the perl script with -MO=Deparse and got

```
use List::MoreUtils ('uniq');
use Data::Dumper;
use strict 'refs';
my(@x) = (3, 2);
my(@y) = (4, 3);
print "unique results \n";
print Dumper([uniq(@x, @y)]);
print "sorted unique results\n";
print Dumper([(sort uniq @x, @y)]);
```

My interpretation is that perl decided to remove the parentheses from uniq(@x,@y) and using uniq as a function of sort.

Why did perl decide to do it?

How can i avoid these and similar pitfalls?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`sort` builtin](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) accepts a subroutine name or block as first argument which is passed two items. It then must return a number which determines the order between the items. These snippets all do the same:

```
use feature 'say';
my @letters = qw/a c a d b/;

say "== 1 ==";
say for sort @letters;

say "== 2 ==";
say for sort { $a cmp $b } @letters;

say "== 3 ==";
sub func1 { $a cmp $b }
say for sort func1 @letters;

say "== 4 ==";
sub func2 ($$) { $_[0] cmp $_[1] }  # special case for $$ prototype
say for sort func2 @letters;
```

Notice that there isn't any comma between the function name and the list, and note that the parens in Perl are primarly used to determine precedence – `sort func1 @letters` and `sort func1 (@letters)` are the same, and neither executes `func1(@letters)`.

To disambiguate, place a `+` before the function name:

```
sort +uniq @letters;
```

To avoid such unexpected behaviour, the best solution is to read the docs when you aren't sure how a certain builtin behaves – unfortunately, many have some special parsing rules.

Comment: I did not understand for 100 percent why it does not execute uniq beforehand and then uses sort LIST, but i assume that it prefers the sort SUBNAME LIST form. What does the + sign mean?

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang yes, the problem is that your code was parsed as `sort SUBNAME LIST`. The unary `+` forbids this interpretation and forces “normal” invocation of `uniq`. It is important to remember that `sort` isn't a subroutine – it is a keyword just like `foreach` or `grep`.

Comment: `DWIM` fails here as one would expect same behavior like for `sort grep` or `sort map`

Comment: But `map` and `grep` are built-ins, so the disambiguation heuristic knows what they do and that you're unlikely to be trying to use them as a custom sort sub.

Comment: @Сухой27, `grep` and `map` are operators, not valid sub names.

Answer (score 3):

You could put parenthesis arround the uniq fonction:

```
print Dumper([sort (uniq(@x,@y))]);
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          3,
          4
        ];
```

Comment: Yes. This could have solved it, but my question is why does perl work this way.

Comment: It just does. Certain pieces of Perl syntax are ambiguous, and perl needs to guess your intent. It doesn't always guess right.

Comment: There's no ambiguity here or guessing here. The more specific syntax (`sort SUBNAME LIST`) takes precedence over the less specific syntax (`sort LIST`).