# Perl parser acts wierdly with sort and uniq

Tags: perl

Hi I am a newbie in Perl. I have trouble in understanding the operator precedence. I found a program in Wikipedia page for Ruby

```
"Nice Day Isn't It?".downcase.split("").uniq.sort.join # => " '?acdeinsty"
```

I tried the same thing in Perl but the parser acts wierdly. I have the following program

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq distinct) ;

    my $hello = q/Nice Day Isn't It?/ ;

    print join ('', sort ( List::MoreUtils::uniq (split(//, lc $hello ))));  # &List::MoreUtils::uniq parses correctly and I need to include & before call.

    print "\n";

    print join('', sort( List::MoreUtils::uniq(split(//, lc $hello, 0))));
```

Output :

```
   '?acdeiiinnstty
 '?acdeinsty
```

Also I tried for to look how Perl parses the code with B::Deparse module and here is the output

```
perl -MO=Deparse test.pl
use List::MoreUtils ('uniq', 'distinct');
use warnings;
use strict 'refs';
my $hello = q[Nice Day Isn't It?];
print join('', (sort List::MoreUtils::uniq split(//, lc $hello, 0)));
print "\n";
print join('', sort(&List::MoreUtils::uniq(split(//, lc $hello, 0))));
test.pl syntax OK
```

I also get the warning when I simply use uniq as I might clash with future reserved keywords. Any useful links to study about the list precedence and associativity will be very helpful. I referred to perlop Term and list operator section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does sort with uniq not work together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239503/why-does-sort-with-uniq-not-work-together)

Comment: @mpapec . Sorry I dint look up the search. Also the space between List::MoreUtils::uniq and following paranthesis seems to be the gotcha with space making uniq a function of sort and without space its a separate function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the docs for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).  If you pass it a sub name it will try to use that for the sorting.

That's why the following are different:

```
print join '', sort(uniq(split //, lc $hello));
# Prints:  ?acdeinsty

print join '', sort uniq(split //, lc $hello);
# Prints: nice day isn't it?
```

The second one is equivalent to:

```
print join '', sort {uniq} (split //, lc $hello);
```

The `uniq` function will return `0` for all tests, claiming that each character is equal.  Therefore `sort` will maintain the same order, reducing the above code to just:

```
print join '', split //, lc $hello;
```

One trick to keep `sort` from using the next sub as a comparator is to put a `+` sign in front of the sub name (ty mpapec):

```
print join '', sort +uniq split //, lc $hello;
```

Comment: Thanks @Miller . I looked up the docs but I couldn't figure out how to change uniq as a separate function instead of a function used for sort. mpapec answer 

print join ('', sort (+uniq (split(//, lc $hello ))));

too gave the answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use more parenthesis, or use the trick that mpapec suggested.  Added that to my answer.